# What is a StatusBar?

Tags: react-native

the official documentation here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar only states:

> Component to control the app status bar.

which means absolutely nothing.  the docs don't even show an example of what one might look like

the template I'm using has one but I don't see it on screen and if I remove it nothing changes, so I'm wondering if this is support for some kind of functionality I might not need

what is it and why do I care?

p.s. I do see this:

[image: top of the emulator]

which appears irrespective of whether I include the component or not

Answer (score 2):

[image: Status Bar]

The status bar is the system header that displays time, notifications, battery, etc.

Including this in your component won't add any views but will style the status bar according to the props you pass it.

Some common use cases for this component include:

#### Colouring the bar to match your app's style

```
<StatusBar backgroundColor='green'/>
```

#### Hiding the bar

```
<StatusBar hidden/>
```

#### Getting the height for padding your component

```
<View style={{marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight}}/>
```

Comment: I see.  I don't see it in the iOS emulator

Comment: see my edit to the post for a picture of what I see

Comment: The status bar will appear unless you include the `StatusBar` component with the `hidden` prop set to true.

Comment: I'm including it just like this `<StatusBar />` so there's no styling but I don't see anything.  I'm using the iPhone 11 emulator

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see anything"? The status bar will appear as it does in your screenshot unless you include a `<StatusBar/>` component with props to modify it's state in some way (see my edit).

Comment: oddly I had included it just for testing and then removed it but now I don't see the status bar (as shown in my picture above) at all.  this stuff is so squirrely